# DBUnit order for dataset

Tags: dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I have the following quite strange dataset for DBUnit:

```
<persons id = "1"
         first_name ="TestName99"
         second_name = "TestSecondName"
         father_name = "TestFatherName"
         phone_number = "123456789"
         date_of_birth = "1985-12-12 00:16:14"
         role = "ROLE_OWNER"
         date_of_creation = "2016-09-23 23:09:28"
         enable = "1" />

<carwash id = "1"
         name = "TestCarWash"
         address = "test car wash address "
         phone_number = " 123456789"
         box_count = "5"
         first_shift = "08:00:00"
         second_shift = "20:00:00"
         created_by = "1"
         date_of_creation = "2016-09-23 23:09:28"
         enable = "1" />

<persons id = "2"
         first_name ="TestName100"
         second_name = "TestSecondName"
         father_name = "TestFatherName"
         phone_number = "123456789"
         date_of_birth = "1985-12-12 00:16:14"
         role = "ROLE_WASHERMAN"
         date_of_creation = "2016-09-23 23:09:28"
         carwash = "1"
         enable = "1" />
```

the most strange thinks is `persons` table has foreign key to `carwash` however this column is nullable (therefore you cannot find `carwash` in person with `id=1`) and `carwash` table has FK to `persons` in column `create_by`

This scheme leads to special order for put data in DB. As I understand  DBUnit doesn't put value in DB based on order the value mentioned in dataset by default. And consequently when this dataset is executing it lead to exception

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_pitstop`.`persons`, CONSTRAINT `persons_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`carwash`) REFERENCES `carwash` (`id`))
```

Is any way to push DBUnit put data in DB in string order as it mentioned in xml ?

Comment: Did you found any solution to execute inserts in dataset order?

Answer (score 1):

In your dataset.xml file you must specify tables in correctly insertion order, this means, the basic tables first and then the related tables. This way and using **DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT**, tables will be deleted correctly too (related tables first and then basic tables).

Your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>

<carwash id = "1"
     name = "TestCarWash"
     address = "test car wash address "
     phone_number = " 123456789"
     box_count = "5"
     first_shift = "08:00:00"
     second_shift = "20:00:00"
     created_by = "1"
     date_of_creation = "2016-09-23 23:09:28"
     enable = "1" />

<persons id = "1"
     first_name ="TestName99"
     second_name = "TestSecondName"
     father_name = "TestFatherName"
     phone_number = "123456789"
     date_of_birth = "1985-12-12 00:16:14"
     role = "ROLE_OWNER"
     date_of_creation = "2016-09-23 23:09:28"
     enable = "1" />

<persons id = "2"
     first_name ="TestName100"
     second_name = "TestSecondName"
     father_name = "TestFatherName"
     phone_number = "123456789"
     date_of_birth = "1985-12-12 00:16:14"
     role = "ROLE_WASHERMAN"
     date_of_creation = "2016-09-23 23:09:28"
     carwash = "1"
     enable = "1" />

</dataset>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But sometimes you can't order the tables because there are some FK dependencies and the ideal would be to respect dataset order instead of inserting all registers from each table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it is a SQL constraint violation from the database, not a dbUnit issue.  Is Persons.carwash a nonnullable column, or requiring FK from Carwash? dbUnit cannot override database constraints, just as your own code cannot.

Comment: I don't want to override. I need that person with id =1 will be put in DB first than carwash should be put and only after that person id =2. By default DBUnit want to put all persons and only then carwash and it's lead to exception